# How to send file from server to multiple clients at a time in mfc using sockets?

Tags: visual-c++, sockets, mfc, asyncsocket

I am making simple one on server side & one on client side application for transfering file from one location to another location or from one computer to another computer if computers are in network.

I used the code from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SocketFileTransfer.aspx. It is working & file transfered successfully.

But i need to transfer file from server to multiple clients at a time. I mean on server, there should be more than two client can connect & they can receive file at same time.

I don't know how to maintain queue for that & how to pass **CSocket** object to method using Threading & any other way.

I also don't know how to prepare queue of CSocket objects.

So, please if you have any solution or alternative way then please tell me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating thread for each client will transfer file to each client at a time.